# Your PHP version is 7.0.6. The required PHP version is ~7.0.13|~7.1.0

Tags: php, magento2, mediatemple

I'm trying to install Magento-CE 2.2.5 on my MediaTemple server (GridServer)

When I ran the startup installation, I got the following warning:

> Magento supports PHP 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later

I changed the version of my server, to version 7.0.6 but when I do this I get the following error:

[image: error message]

Does anyone know how to avoid this? There is some patch or some way to install it in version 7.0.6 and I have no way to put another version on my server.

Comment: There were [issues with PHP 7.0.x that were resolved in 7.0.13](http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.0.13), it is recommended to upgrade PHP to 7.0.13 or later. If possible you should always use the latest security patch for 7.0, currently 7.0.31, to ensure your application is not vulnerable to exploits and benefits from any resolved issues.

Comment: what do you see when you issue this command #php -v on your terminal?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion fyrye but as I commented on my message my web is hosted on a shared server "MediaTemple" and for this reason I can not change the PHP version, so my question is: "how can I install magento in that php version? some patch? or another way?

Comment: If Magento says that the minimum version of 7.0 it will accept is 7.0.13, then that is the version you need to aim for. Ask MediaTemple if you can move to a server that supports that, or that supports 7.1. If they cannot then either use a VPS or move to a different shared hosting company.